# Change pyspark dataframe header names using schema

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have few csv with around 10  columns and I get the data from different sources and header names are also different. I am trying to change the header names using schema as below.

```
def transform(df):
   schema = StructType([StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
                        StructField('ID', IntegerType(), True),
                        StructField('Volume', DoubleType(), True),
                        StructField('GrossAmount', DoubleType(), True)])
   
    df_transform = spark.createDataFrame(data = df, schema = schema)
    return df_transform

df = transform(spark.read.csv("data1.csv", header = True, inferSchema = True))
```

But I get teh following error

*TypeError: data is already a DataFrame*

Please let me know how to achieve this. I want to write a function and hence I can use the same on other dataframes too. Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to change column names, you can use `df2 = df.toDF('Name', 'ID', ...)`

Comment: Why don't you pass the schema when you read the csv files? `df.read.csv(..., schema=custom_schema`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define schema at file reading level.

```
mySchema = StructType([StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
                        StructField('ID', IntegerType(), True),
                        StructField('Volume', DoubleType(), True),
                        StructField('GrossAmount', DoubleType(), True)])
   
df = spark.read.csv("data1.csv", header = True, schema = mySchema)
```

As you can see data is already a dataframe so if you try create a dataframe by this command this will give you error.

```
spark.createDataFrame(data = df, schema = schema)
```

On a separate note python UDF are costly in performance, so it is recommended to avoid if you can avail spark functionality instead of UDF.